# Redirect constructor with no arguments to a base class ctor with argument

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm trying to make a class *Bar* that extends a class *Foo*.  The code of *Foo* is beyond my control.

When someone makes a new instance of *Bar* (by writing something like *Bar x = new Bar();*) I want this to trigger a call to the *Foo* constructor that takes an input argument.

Basically:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo(string message) { print("The new Foo says: " + message); }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    public Bar() : base(this.GetType()) { }
}
```

So when someone uses *new Bar()*, it should print out *The new Foo says: Bar*.  (Assuming there's a *print* function, which isn't the point here.)

Instead, C# complains because I'm trying to compute a result in the arguments to the base constructor.

Remember, *Foo* is beyond my reach, so I can't change any code in *Foo*.

Comment: Post the exact error message. This code seems correct.

Comment: What is the exact ctor for Foo?  Foo(char[]) maybe?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, you're right, I just edited the question as I realized it was actually a slightly different problem.

Comment: @Joe it's not _slightly_ different, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `this` before the actual constructor of a class, as only the parameters and static members (as the `static` constructor is run before any non-static ones) are accessable in that context. The runtime first needs to construct any classes you inherit from before you are able to access `this`.

As a workaround, you can use the `typeof` operator:

```
class Bar : Foo {
    public Bar() : base(typeof(Bar).ToString()) { }
}
```

Of course, this isn't portable, but is probably the best thing you'll be able to come up with.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is my first question on here.

Comment: The constructor args/params aren't the only things accessible. Static members, for one, can also be used. But that's a pretty good workaround, assuming there won't be anything deriving from `Bar` later on or something.

Comment: Obviously, as the (implicit) static constructor and field initializer is run before.

Answer (score 1):

`this.GetType()` will not work to as an initialization routine.

You can't execute code that is passed to the base class but relies on the current instance.  This is logical, as the base class constructor is executed *first*.

However, if you're passing a type, you can use `typeof` instead of `GetType()`.

The following code runs and compiles correctly:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    using System;

    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var foo = new Bar();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public Foo(Type type) { Console.WriteLine("The type of Foo is: " + type.ToString()); }
    }

    class Bar : Foo
    {
        public Bar() : base(typeof(Bar)) { }
    }
}
```

Upon execution, this prints to the console:

> The type of Foo is: TestNamespace.Bar